# <meta name="keywords" content="abc, efg" not working

Tags: html, web-applications, keyword, meta-tags

I have added meta tags as shown below.

```
<meta name="keywords" content="abc, efg" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

I was expecting this to work with google search however when I search for abc (for example purpose), I don't see my site in google. So just curious that above meta tag is not working.

HTML generated file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/themes/sam/theme.css?ln=primefaces" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/rfRes/skinning.ecss?db=eAHL6rC8BQAEkAIG" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/buttonStyles.css?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/menuss.css?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/setFontForAll.css?ln=css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/faces/javax.faces.resource/js/dropdownmenu.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/faces/javax.faces.resource/js/menu.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/menus_w.css?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/menus.css?ln=css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/faces/javax.faces.resource/myFont.css?ln=css" />

    <meta name="keywords" content="abc, efg, xyz" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>
        Welcome to My Site
    </title>
</head>
```

Please let me know what I am missing so that on search I should get my site in google.

Comment: If you thought those meta tags actually did anything... no, they don't do anything.

Comment: @BoltClock : Then what should I do to get my site in google search?

Comment: Write good content. Publish it online. Wait. These things come naturally and *take time*; you can't force them. Also make sure you don't have any robots.txt blocking out search engines...

Comment: @BoltClock : Ohhh... I  think I need to wait then.... Well thanks for that... I have good content... ABC, EFG are just for example purpose :) I will check tomorrow morning

Comment: @BoltClock : As you give answer "Wait, take time", what should I do to this question? No answer to accept :P

Comment: You should also [submit your site to google](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url) - that way it'll crawl it soon instead of only after it found a link to it somewhere else.

Comment: @FahimParkar Delete/close it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keywords in `html:meta` are pretty much ignored by all systems that matter because they usually do not reflect the content of the page very well. Aspects that do matter include `meta name="description"` (this can be used as a description on a search results page); keyword density of the content (do not use your keywords too much, but obviously not too little either); whether or not the keyword(s) appear in the URL (and, preferably, the domain name); how many websites and webpages link to your page; the rating of the entities that refer to your page; how long the content exists (longer is better); how often the websites that hosts your content is updated (more often is better); how accessible your content is to agents (both people as robots); how much you pay to Google (this should be obvious); et cetera.

So, yeah, short answer: it does not work, but other things do.

Also, make sure an entity that is known at Google links to your content. If not, Google will have a very hard time finding it. You can submit your websites/webpage to Google directly, but I have been told you get a better initial rank if Google finds your content by following a referring link itself.

Comment: Besides the meta description it's usually a good idea to add the related opengraph tags, too, as sites like facebook use them to get a description of your site when someone links to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, google will not include your website in the search results until a period of time. 
I recommend using google webmaster to increase your chances of getting your site on their search results.

meta elements are used to explain the content on your site. It does not help you with showing your page on google until your website becomes popular.

Answer (score 0):

There's a whole philosophy in web-development called SEO (or Search Engine Optimization).

The main points are these:

- Have your website use a good, clean, semantic HTML markup.
- Write high quality content.
- Don't have duplicate content (or make sure your URL rewriting doesn't allow it).
- Having external sites which are related to your subject helps a lot (For instance, having a link to a CSS-Tricks article from this site is more helpful than one posted in a gaming forum).
- Wait. Google takes the uptime of your website into an account, more mature, stable, and veteran websites get better search results.
- Your keywords should appear in your content, in your headlines and titles, and just about everywhere. Don't overdo it though!

**[This is a great website to get you started](http://searchengineland.com/)**.

---

As for the specific question: `<meta>` tags has little to no effect in search engine results. Google literally ignores them.